# added nodejs backend to a ubontu 22 server. using nginx, I certbot won't authorize the domains

Tags: node.js, nginx, vps, certbot

short intro: working to be frontend dev. added some api's to have a more dynamic portfolio. bought a VPS so i can integrate the backend logic. i've tried following multiple tutorials some messing with nginx and some going into regis. but i keep getting the same error:

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: www1.example.com
  Type:   dns
  Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www1.example.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain; DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for www1.example.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

  Domain: example.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 2a02:4780:b:969:0:208d:9c5:2: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/AIPd-pLiiWupZ371YxSHe1_802TIg_sStJOX5lTNkS4: 404

  Domain: www.example.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 2a02:4780:b:969:0:208d:9c5:2: Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/PSLlRQudh23aYRQSrPVEMcf3aEe3pBPhkP_X6JdIzeI: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary nginx configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure the listed domains point to this nginx server and that it is accessible from the internet.
```

ive used  letsdebug and it says it's likely a fire wall problem.
(i don't know what's up with the www1 domain. as i didn't put that in but left it to show full code.)

as of now, everything is repo'd from github, the VPS cloudpanel has the domain, but don't know if i need to manually update any of those settings. but when i plug in the url :xx.xx.xx.xx:3000 (with ufw disabled) it gives me the html of the front page, with no css or javascript, console says:
xFailed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

if ufw is enabled then i get nothing. which i beleive i need to use nginx to reverse proxy the 3000 to 80.

see above.

big question is there something i missed setting up the node index.js file?

this has been bothersome for multiple days, and many tutorials later I keep getting the same result.

thanks for the help

Comment: Are the sites reachable with http? Can we see your nginx configuration files for the domains?

Comment: i cannot get them to come up to HTTP, if i type in 'example.com' it gets 404 not found. which is another item i'm looking into 

i beleive i did everything correct with changing the dns AA and www to the server. but the domain doesn't populate with even the html as stated above with the server:3000.

i also noticed in the VPS the file manager doesn't contain the files that i cloned from the repo. i can ssh into the server, go to the app directory and 'npm start' and it runs, but i don't know how to access the files on the cloud panel.

i can get the  /etc/nginx/nginx. conf files.

Comment: Currently I simply don't understand all the problems that are accouring and what you do in general. Can you be a little bit more structured about what you did, what you are trying, what is working and what do you want but cannot achieve?
If you enable ufw you just need to allow port 3000 `ufw allow 3000` and you should be able to access the webserver on that port.
The error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` sounds like you try to load your content with `https` instead of `http`.